# In a von Neumann factor, trace of nonzero projection is strictly positive

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I'm following Popa and Anantharaman's "An introduction to $II_1$ factors" and in Proposition 4.1.3 they prove that:

*A von Neumann factor $M$ has at most one tracial state, and then such a tracial state is faithful.*

In the proof, it seems like they use that if $\tau$ is a tracial state on $M$ then $\tau(p) > 0$ for any projection $p \neq 0$. Is that true, and if so how would one go about showing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are in a factor, you can always compare projections. So, given any $p$, you can find projections $p_1,\ldots,p_n,r$, with $p_j\sim p$, $r\prec p$, and $r+\sum_jp_j=1$. If $\tau(p)=0$, then $\tau(p_j)=0$ for all $j$, and also $\tau(r)=0$, since $r\sim r_0\leq p$ and $\tau$ is positive. So you get $\tau(1)=0$, contradicting that $\tau$ is a state.

The construction of the projections is trivial: start with $p_1=p$. If $p\prec 1-p_1$, then you have $p\sim p_2\leq 1-p_1$ for some projection $p_2$; and you keep going. Eventually, you will have $p\succ 1-p_1-\cdots -p_n$, so there exists $r\leq 1-p_1-\cdots-p_n$ with $r\prec p$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry if it's obvious, but how do you know there is some $n$ for which $p \succ 1 - p_1 - \cdots - p_n$?

Comment: Yeah, it's not entirely obvious; it depends a bit on what assumptions you have (like whether you know that $M$ is finite or not). In any case, if the construction goes on infinitely, you would have infinitely many equivalent, pairwise orthogonal, projections. Then by standards arguments $$p_1+p_2+\cdots\sim p_2+p_3+\cdots$$ Applying $\tau$ to both sides you get that $$\tau(p_1)+\tau(p_2+\cdots)=\tau(p_2+\cdots),$$ so $\tau(p_1)=0$.

Comment: So just to clarify: is it enough for $M$ just to be a factor with a tracial state $\tau$ to guarantee $\tau(p) > 0$ for all $p \in \mathcal{P}(M) \setminus \{0\}$, or do we need some extra assumptions to know we can write $1$ as above? Thank you again.

Comment: Yes, any factor with a tracial state.